# How do I change the behavior of the tag select popup?

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

When you create a new element, you can assign tags to it, but the tags window constantly jumps around the screen as you type. Which is very annoying if you want to quickly select with the mouse by ready-made tags.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgr98.jpg

And here http://eucaly-tw5.tiddlyspot.com/ the owner has already screwed something up and the window does not move, and of course it is more convenient.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JhMN.jpg

What parameters need to be changed in order to get the same effect on myself?

Comment: I don't understand you problem, did you find a solution? If not this might be a browser-specific issue, did you try with a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is controlled via CSS. One option would be to add the following value to a sitewide stylesheet (tagged `$:/tags/Stylesheet`):

```
.tc-edit-add-tag {
    display: unset;
}
```